# Building Tabs with JQuery, the most efficient and effective way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

quick question and I know it might seem easy to very experienced programmers out there but I'm only learning and I'm trying to learn about best practices and how to do things most efficiently, so please bear with me! I'd really appreciate any advice.

I'm working with `JQuery`and I'm trying to make a simple Tab functionality. The way I've done it is I've created a `ul` containing multiple `li` then depending on the `li` clicked I update the content in a `div` on the page.

I've implemented this in JSFiddle so you can see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/oeh7Lj62/

I'm wondering If this is a good approach to making Tabs? and whether or not the way I show the one  I click and hide the others is efficient, because let's say for example I had 20 tabs, would I need to have a `show()` for the tab clicked and `hide()` for the other 19? Or is there a more effective way of `hiding` the other tabs?

Again, I know it's a simple enough question but I'm just looking for advice on how to improve. Many thanks.

This is my `js`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#mylist li').click(function (e) {
                    var tab = $(this).html();
                    if (tab == "one") {
                        $('#tab-1-list').show();
                        $('#tab-2-list').hide();
                        $('#tab-3-list').hide();
                    }
                    else if (tab == "two")
                    {
                        $('#tab-2-list').show();
                        $('#tab-1-list').hide();
                        $('#tab-3-list').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#tab-3-list').show();
                        $('#tab-1-list').hide();
                        $('#tab-2-list').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is my `html`

```
<ul id="mylist">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>        
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-content">
            <ul id="tab-1-list">
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="tab-2-list">
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="tab-3-list">
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
                <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my `css`

```
#tab-1-list{display:none;}
#tab-2-list{display:none;}
#tab-3-list{display:none;}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered (as "this is the best way") as there is many different ways to get this done, the way you have done it by all means is fine. Are they shorter ways.. yeah sure but nothing thats going to dramatically affect a simple thing like this. As for "if there where 20 tabs" bit you could put a class on all the tab content or just hide all children of a parent and then show the tab you want.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that there is definitely a large number of ways to do it, I guess in the past whenever I've done things "my way" it goes against best practice so I was curious, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Javacadabra: [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2Qw/) quite a simple implementation, if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Here is a demo making your code very slightly shorter. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oeh7Lj62/2/). So you hide all the tab contents and then show the tab content you want, saves you from manually hiding all of the other tab contents. Better ways would including using frameworks.

Comment: Hey @Ruddy I like your Fiddle the most, As you mentioned it's only slightly shorter, but It's what I was looking for. If you want to post it as an Answer I will gladly accept. Thank you also jbutler483 that is a fantastic fiddle.

Comment: @Javacadabra I would defiantly look into using some of answers below as they make life a lot easier. You don't have to keep rewriting "if tab 1"..."else if tab 2".

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most efficient way would be using classes instead of ids.

Attach a click event to the `li`s that are descendants of `#mylist`, get the index of the current `li` that was clicked using `$(this).index()` and `.show()` the element with class name `.tab` that has the same index using the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector.

```js
$('#mylist > li').click(function() {
  $('.tab').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-content">
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-1-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-2-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-3-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

You could also use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) instead of `.show()` and `.hide()` respectively.

```js
$('#mylist > li').click(function() {
  $('.tab').fadeOut().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#tab-content {
  position: relative;
}
.tab {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-content">
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-1-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-2-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab" id="tab-3-list">
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
    <li>This is a bullet point for Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask just one question @chipChocolate.py, I'm a little confused as to what the `$(.tab).hide()` part of your answer is doing, I understand the rest, it's just that bit. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Javacadabra - That will hide all `.tab` elements before showing any `.tab`.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to use jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/).
Many other features too.

- Accordion
- Autocomplete
- Button
- Datepicker
- Dialog
- Menu
- etc

**jQuery UI tab Example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: I will indeed use `JQuery UI` in future projects and such I just wanted to gain better understanding into the logic behind what is going on. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oeh7Lj62/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mylist li').click(function (e) {
        var index = +($(this).index())+1;
        $('#tab-content ul').hide();
        $('#tab-'+index+'-list').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possibility :

**HTLM**

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li rel="tab-1-list">one</li>
    <li rel="tab-2-list">two</li>
    <li rel="tab-3-list">three</li>        
</ul>
```

I added a attribute `rel` for referencing the corresponding tabs via `id`

**JQuery**

```
$('#mylist li').click(function (e) {
    rel = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#tab-content ul').hide(); //hide all tabs

    $('#' + rel).show(); //just show the corresponding
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eyum6jmb/)**

Additionally you can have a look at Jquery UIs [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).
[Here](http://keith-wood.name/uitabs.html) are a few example of how you can style these tabs.